# Elasticsearch Backup - 800gb indice, 200gb disk space left

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch indice that is currently 800gb.

I want to create a backup snapshot and store it offsite in the cloud. However, I only have 200gb of remaining local disk space.

Is there a way I can backup the whole indice to the cloud, perhaps in batches as I don't have enough local disk space remaining to store it entirely - what is the best solution here?

Comment: You can have a snapshot in the cloud, elasticsearch supports snapshots in AWS S3, Azure and Google Cloud. [Elasticsearch Snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/modules-snapshots.html)

Comment: Even without the leftover space on disk?

Comment: Yes, if your snapshot is in the cloud (S3, Azure, Google Cloud), elasticsearch will save the data in your account in the cloud and after that you can delete your local indice, just remind that this have a cost both to store the data in the cloud and to retrieve when you need.